# How to map the angular 5 service response to JSON object

Tags: json, angular, service, mapping

In the earlier angular version, in our service, we could simply map the response to a JSON object as follow :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable()
export class MakeService {
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  getMakes(){
    return this.http.get('/api/myAPI')
    .map(res=>res.json());
  }
}
```

However, in angular 5 we don't have HTTP anymore and we have to use HttpClient instead, what should be added to the code above to work in angular5.

my component looks like :

```
  makes : any[]; 
  constructor(private makeservice: MakeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.makeservice.getMakes().subscribe(makes=>{
    this.makes=makes;
    console.log("MAKES",this.makes);
    });
  }
```

simply by removing the ":any[]" data type from make it will work, but I need to pass the JSON object to component from service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following,

```
getMakes(){
    return this.http.get('/api/myAPI')  
}
```

and in component,

```
constructor(public data:DMakeService ){
    this.data.getMakes().subscribe(data=>{
      console.log(data);
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to map to JSON anymore, so this is sufficient:

```
getMakes(){
  return this.http.get('/api/myAPI');
}
```

This returns an Observable, however, not a Promise, so you'd have to subscribe the return value to get the result. If you want to keep working with promises, you can do this:

```
getMakes(){
  return this.http.get('/api/myAPI').toPromise();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According [here](https://angular.io/guide/http#always-subscribe). You should always subscribe to any request made by `httpclient`

> **Always subscribe!**
>
> An HttpClient method does not begin its HTTP request until you call
>   subscribe() on the observable returned by that method. This is true
>   for all HttpClient methods.

```
const req = http.get<Heroes>('/api/heroes');
    // 0 requests made - .subscribe() not called.
    req.subscribe();
    // 1 request made.
    req.subscribe();
    // 2 requests made.
```